# RecyclerView not displaying SQLite Data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

[GIF OF ACTIVITY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sJEV.gif) **<--------**

What I am trying to do is simply display my **SQLite Data** from a **RecyclerView Adapter**, some how it **partially** works but not concretely.
If you have any feedback don't hesitate to indulge me please!

Heres the relevant code:

**MachineCreation.java**

```
public class MachineCreation extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etName, etLocation;
private Button mButton;
private DBHelpter mDBHelpter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_machine_creation);

    mDBHelpter = new DBHelpter(this);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLocation);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = String.valueOf(etName.getText());
            String location = String.valueOf(etLocation.getText());
            mDBHelpter.insertNewMachine(name, location);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MachineCreation.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**machines_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="CALDAS"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="$ 0.0"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/tvMoney"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DBHelpter mDBHelpter;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ArrayList<MachinesClass> mList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDBHelpter = new DBHelpter(this);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvNew);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MachinesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mList));

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="tech.destinum.machines.MainActivity"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rvNew"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**DBHelper**

```
public class DBHelpter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "machines.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_MACHINES = "machines";
public static final String MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION = "location";
public static final String MACHINES_ID = "id";

public static final String TABLE_INCOME = "income";
public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY = "money";
public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_DATE = "date";
public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE = "note";
public static final String INCOME_ID = "id";

public DBHelpter(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query1 = String.format("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MACHINES + "("
        + MACHINES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL)",
            TABLE_MACHINES, MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME, MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION, MACHINES_ID);

    String query2 = String.format("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INCOME + "("
        + INCOME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY + " REAL NOT NULL, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_DATE + " DATE NOT NULL, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT NOT NULL)",
            TABLE_INCOME, INCOME_ID, INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY, INCOME_COLUMN_DATE, INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE);
    db.execSQL(query1);
    db.execSQL(query2);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query1 = String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MACHINES);
    String query2 = String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INCOME);
    db.execSQL(query1);
    db.execSQL(query2);
    onCreate(db);

}

public void insertNewMachine(String name, String location){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION, location);
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_MACHINES, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    db.close();
}

public void updateMachine(long id, String name, String location){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION, location);
    db.update(TABLE_MACHINES, values, "id = ?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
    db.close();
}

public void deleteMachine(long id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_MACHINES, "id = ?", new String[]{id + ""});
    db.close();
}

public ArrayList<MachinesClass> getAllMachines(){
    ArrayList<MachinesClass> machinesList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MACHINES, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MACHINES_ID));
        final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME));
        final String location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION));
        machinesList.add(new MachinesClass(id, name, location));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return machinesList;
}
```

}

**MachinesClass.java**

```
public class MachinesClass {
public long id;
public String name, location;

public MachinesClass(long id, String name, String location) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
}
```

}

**MachinesAdapter.java**

```
public class MachinesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MachinesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<MachinesClass> machinesList = new ArrayList<MachinesClass>();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public MachinesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MachinesClass> machinesList){
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.machinesList = machinesList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.machines_list, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MachinesClass item = machinesList.get(position);
    holder.mLocation.setText(item.location);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return machinesList != null ? machinesList.size() : 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView mLocation, mMoney;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mLocation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
        mMoney = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMoney);
    }
}
```

}

---

When I change in my **MainActivity.java** the line:

- `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MachinesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mList));`

to

- `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MachinesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mList =
  mDBHelpter.getAllMachines()));`

I get the next **Error**.

I know I have to make the call to the **DBHelper** to get all machines, but I do not know how to do it **correctly**.

**ERROR**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: tech.destinum.machines, PID: 3604
              java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                  at tech.destinum.machines.MachinesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MachinesAdapter.java:33)
                  at tech.destinum.machines.MachinesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MachinesAdapter.java:14)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6279)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6312)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5258)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5521)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5363)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5359)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2141)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1525)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1488)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:585)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3506)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3254)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3767)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1167)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:852)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:871)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                at android.
```

Comment: `machinesList.clear();` - Why are you clearing your list in `onBindViewHolder()`?

Comment: **Updated** Code, removed machinesList.clear(). Still working as the GIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while digging up I found a **SOLUTION**, I had to change the **onBindViewHolder** method, remove 2 lines. The **machinesList.clear** and **notifyDataSetChanged()**.

Thanks everyone who had an input!

Answer (score 0):

In onBindViewHolder you are clearing the machinesList using machinesList.clear(); and the reusing it which i think is a mistake.

Comment: **Updated** Code, removed machinesList.clear(). Still working as the GIF.

Comment: @Ispam Mark this question as answered so that people can skip this question while looking up for unanswered questions.

Comment: You have to wait **24 Hours** before you can accept your own answer.